# Parallelize for loop with multiple XGBoost predictions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, xgboost, concurrent.futures

I have multiple different XGBoost models, which are already trained. Now I want to predict a given input with each of these models. When I try to parallelize them, I end up in a deadlock. Is there a way to solve this? The next input is influenced by the output of the predictions so i cannot simply collect them and predict them all at once.

```
def parallel_model(input, model):
    reward = model.predict(input)
    return reward

def main():
    reward = 0
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        for r in pool.map(parallel_model, inputs, models):
             reward += r
```

Comment: Parallelize those XGB models that don't have any intermediate output relationship, and those that are not related can be parallelized. You wont be able to parallelize 2 XGB models where one of them requires the output of another.

Comment: @GautamChettiar The ones that I parallelize here are not dependent on each other. At each timestep `n`, I get `k` input whose result will influence the inputs at timestep `n+1`.